# Kamailio ERROR cfgtrace in kamailio.cfg

Tags: kamailio

I am trying to setup Kamailio server with topoh module (I want to extend topoh module and develop my own module) but when I start `kamailio`, the following errors appear:

```
0(3446) WARNING: <core> [socket_info.c:1407]: fix_hostname(): WARNING: fix_hostname: could not rev. resolve 192.168.188.143
WARNING: no fork mode 
 0(3446) INFO: <core> [tcp_main.c:4846]: init_tcp(): init_tcp: using epoll_lt as the io watch method (auto detected)
 0(3446) INFO: rr [../outbound/api.h:49]: ob_load_api(): Failed to import bind_ob
 0(3446) INFO: rr [rr_mod.c:159]: mod_init(): outbound module not available
 0(3446) INFO: usrloc [hslot.c:53]: ul_init_locks(): locks array size 512
 0(3446) INFO: auth [auth_mod.c:350]: mod_init(): auth: qop set, but nonce-count (nc_enabled) support disabled
 0(3446) INFO: <core> [udp_server.c:179]: probe_max_receive_buffer(): INFO: udp_init: SO_RCVBUF is initially 163840
 0(3446) INFO: <core> [udp_server.c:230]: probe_max_receive_buffer(): INFO: udp_init: SO_RCVBUF is finally 327680
 4(3451) INFO: ctl [io_listener.c:225]: io_listen_loop(): io_listen_loop:  using epoll_lt io watch method (config)
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=469 a=5 n=route
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=579 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=574 a=25 n=mf_process_maxfwd_header
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=584 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=579 a=26 n=sanity_check
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=472 a=5 n=route
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=772 a=2 n=return
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=484 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=475 a=25 n=is_method
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=484 a=5 n=route
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=628 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=588 a=24 n=has_totag
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=488 a=24 n=t_check_trans
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=491 a=5 n=route
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=749 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=736 a=25 n=is_method
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=744 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=739 a=27 n=auth_check
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=740 a=26 n=auth_challenge
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=741 a=2 n=exit
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=469 a=5 n=route
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=579 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=574 a=25 n=mf_process_maxfwd_header
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=584 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=579 a=26 n=sanity_check
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=472 a=5 n=route
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=772 a=2 n=return
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=484 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=475 a=25 n=is_method
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=484 a=5 n=route
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=628 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=588 a=24 n=has_totag
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=488 a=24 n=t_check_trans
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=491 a=5 n=route
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=749 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=736 a=25 n=is_method
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=744 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=739 a=27 n=auth_check
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=746 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=744 a=25 n=is_method
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=756 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=756 a=2 n=return
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=495 a=25 n=remove_hf
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=500 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=496 a=25 n=is_method
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=506 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=500 a=25 n=is_method
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=506 a=5 n=route
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=823 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=511 a=5 n=route
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=716 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=691 a=25 n=is_method
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=721 a=16 n=if
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=716 a=25 n=is_method
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=718 a=26 n=sl_send_reply
 0(3446) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=719 a=2 n=exit
```

Could someone help me to resolve these errors? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find out that these messages are produced by debugger module of Kamailio (http://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/3.2.x/modules/debugger.html). I was able to turn them off by setting `modparam("debugger", "cfgtrace", 0)` in kamailio.cfg

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/3.2.x/modules/debugger.html:

The above example is for registration with default config for version 3.1.0, without authentication. Listed fields are: 'c' - config file; 'l' - line; 'a' - internal action id; 'n' - name of executed action. 'ERROR' prefix is printed because these messages were sent to the L_ERR log level.

Comment: Please add here the example instead of a link, perhaps it gets broken in the future